# File still in downloading on Android Devices from Symfony2 Application

Tags: android, symfony, version-control, header, download

In my application(Symfony2) I have to make available .vcs and .ics files to users from UI to add in their device calendars. I have done it for iPhone but my solution for Android is not working. It keeps in downloading process and never complete.

When I do the same code with plain PHP it works and downloads the file and integrate in device calendar.

### Code for Plain PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=calendar.vcs");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//AT Content Types//AT Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120801T133822Z
CREATED:20120801T042948Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120801T043003Z
SUMMARY:My Event
DTSTART:20130719T000000Z
DTEND:20130720T000000Z
LOCATION:London
URL:https://www.myurl.com/
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

### Code for Symfony2:

```
public function getCalendarAction()
    {
        //$filename = "calendar_".date("Y_m_d_His").".vcs";
        $content = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//AT Content Types//AT Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120801T133822Z
CREATED:20120801T042948Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120801T043003Z
SUMMARY:My Event
DTSTART:20130719T000000Z
DTEND:20130720T000000Z
LOCATION:London
URL:https://www.myurl.com/
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

        $headers = array('Content-Type'     => 'text/x-vCalendar',
            'cache-control'=>'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="calendar.vcs"');

    return new Response($content, 200, $headers);    
}
```

[image][image]

If someone has solution for the problem please post.

Comment: reference to this post
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved now. When I test my code on Server with Valid Trusted SSL Certificate then it downloads the file and integrate in Android device calendar.